# Can dywall vinyl j-channel be used on exterior siding?

Tags: drywall, vinyl-siding

I am having a hard time finding replacement j-channel for my vinyl siding. I am installing new windows, taller than originals, and this means my vertical j-channel I have now won't be long enough. Can i use drywall bead j-channel? I don't see a difference other than no nail fin on the drywall channel. I plan to re-side the house in a few years but not in the budget for awhile.

Answer (score 1):

i would say **NO**. the drywall channel will not be made for long exposure to uv sunlight nor will it be as thick and durable. If you use the drywall channel You will more than likely be replacing it in the near future.

As you know it is not at your local box store, find a siding contractor or supplier in your area and get it from them.

Comment: I would agree that indoor channel will not last. There is channel made for outdoor use.

Comment: Yeah, I know about exterior channel, but like I said in the future, the siding will be replaced. As for UV, it is printable and would need to be painted to match the rest of the trim. My other option is try to carefully remove some from the back of the house and reuse on the front.

Comment: Your question was " can drywall  vinyl  J channel be used on exterior siding"  The answer is no it should not be used  on the exterior.  If you're set on using it then use it but don't ask us to validate your  desire to use it.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't looking for validation, just a cheap alternative. I have options, but since it will be at most 10 years before it's all re-sides, why spend $200 and try to,find the matching j-channel that is probably 15+ years old. I can also use steel channel, but that's $100 for that. I can also side just a portion around the Windows and trim them out, but I'm not sure what siding we will use later on, and again, need a cheap alternative. The only water the Windows get is if I wash the house or the windows, so channeling for water I don't care.

Comment: It is entirely possible, that When I remove the siding to install the windows, the siding will just break. In that case I will have to side it differently. I took a wall put 2 years ago and the siding broke into pieces.